# Apache Avro C++ serialization framework (native type flexibility)

Tags: c++, serialization, avro, primitive

Apache Avro usage for C++ stub generation, native types to c++ (e.g. char[max], bool, etc).

As an example I would like to produce given header stub file:

```
struct CommonStruct
{ 
    int32_t SeqNum;
    char Type[17];
    char InstType;
    // ... etc
};
```

Using apache avro schema, what should I specify? I have tried various different settings, but none of them gave 'char', or 'char[]' types. I'm not confident, that 'string' type is not introducing overhead in processing (heap memory allocation), and whether uint8 (unsigned integer 1 byte) can really replace 'char' type?

#1. Example:
input:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "CommonStruct",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "SeqNum",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "type": { "type": "fixed", "name": "char", "items": "string", "size": 16}
            
        },
        {
            "name": "InstType",
            "type": "bytes"
        }
    ]
}
```

output:

```
struct CommonStruct {
    int32_t SeqNum;
    std::array<uint8_t, 16> Type;
    std::vector<uint8_t> InstType;
    CommonStruct() :
        SeqNum(int32_t()),
        Type(std::array<uint8_t, 16>()),
        InstType(std::vector<uint8_t>())
        { }
};
```

#2 example:
input:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "CommonStruct",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "SeqNum",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "type": { "type": "fixed", "name": "Type", "items": "string", "size": 17}
            
        },
        {
            "name": "InstType",
            "type": { "type": "fixed", "name": "InstType", "size": 1}
        }
    ]
}
```

output:

```
struct CommonStruct {
    int32_t SeqNum;
    std::array<uint8_t, 17> Type;
    std::array<uint8_t, 1> InstType;
    CommonStruct() :
        SeqNum(int32_t()),
        Type(std::array<uint8_t, 17>()),
        InstType(std::array<uint8_t, 1>())
        { }
};
```

My question therefore is:
Is Apache Avro can replicate native C++ types? If it is not possible:
a. Is there an overhead for using 'std::string' instead of char of fixed type? string surely likes to allocate heap memory, but some articles refer that it does allocation statically for short length.
b. Instead of using 'std::string' I see, that it is possible to use std::array<uint8,size> of arbitrary size (above examples), I have not yet experimented of paring encoding/decoding char array sizes to there, but if anyone has an experience in this, would be great to hear, if that is equivalent: 'char[17]' == 'std::array<uint8,17>'? Would conversion practically cause any issues? Would 'std::array<uint8,1>' == 'char' in the above scenario?

Just to add, I am new to Apache Avro serialization, previously have worked only with direct serialization & looking to understand, if avro could potentially be more useful than creating own serialization & de-serialization approach.

I have installed Apache Avro from https://dlcdn.apache.org/avro/avro-1.11.2/cpp/, attempted to generate expected header files (stubs), would have expected to have flexibility to specify native C++ types (e.g. char array of fixed type), but can't find if that's supported.

Comment: Just for a quick update (in case someone would come and seek for similar type question), looks like Avro is made for slightly different purpose, using 'ZigZag' encoding style. So in this case there is no need for any different parts, apart of 'ZigZag' encoding datatypes (https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/api/cpp/html/Zigzag_8hh.html) . This makes sense why natural types are not supported. As of this strong dependency, this does not suit my requirements.